# libssh symbols not found error gcc

Tags: gcc, undefined-symbol, libssh

I am trying to build a simple SSH client from Wil Allsopp's pen testing book.  Working on Mac OS High Sierra with gcc-4.2 with libssh installed using Homebrew.  The simplest version of the code is:

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    return 0;
}
```

However a simple gcc build (`gcc -Wall ssh_client.c`) produces the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_ssh_free", referenced from:
>         _main in ssh_client-aa8f09.o
>
> "_ssh_new", referenced from:
>         _main in ssh_client-aa8f09.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Can anyone explain these errors and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build line doesn't appear to contain any include and linker flags. I imagine it is picking up the headers but not the library for ssh to link against. Have a look into pkgconfig for an easy way to maintain this.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right.  I have been away from c programming and gcc for a very long time.  I will look into the documentation for pkgconfig. Thank you.

Comment: take a look on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074521/link-libssh-with-static-library-libssh-a 
it helped me to build executable, but still need some time to understand how linking works