# link libssh with static library (libssh.a)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, static-linking, libssh

I was trying to link my program with libssh static library.

Following is my simple code copied from libssh tutorial:

```
//sshtest.c
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  ssh_session my_ssh_session;
  my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
  if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
    exit(-1);

  ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

I put library file `libssh.a` into the subdirectory `libs/`

Then compile it with command `gcc sshtest.c -Llibs -lssh -o sshtest`

The output is bunch of undefined reference errors like:

```
libs/libssh.a(wrapper.c.o): In function `crypto_free':
/home/gg/libssh/src/wrapper.c:156: undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
/home/gg/libssh/src/wrapper.c:157: undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
libs/libssh.a(libcrypto.c.o): In function `ssh_reseed':
/home/gg/libssh/src/libcrypto.c:77: undefined reference to `RAND_add'
libs/libssh.a(libcrypto.c.o): In function `sha1_init':
/home/gg/libssh/src/libcrypto.c:84: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
```

The problem can be fixed by copying dynamic library files (`libssh.so, libssh.so.4, libssh.so.4.5.0`) into the `libs/` folder, but I guess the compiler will link with dynamic library in this case.

Can somebody tell me the proper way to link libssh static library? Thank you !!

*Something extra (optional):*

Actually, I was trying to build an ssh server application using includeOS, I try to link dynamic library with it by adding `target_link_libraries` into the `cmakelist.txt`, and I got an error `usr/bin/ld unrecognized option "-Wl,-rpath,path_to_my_sshlib"`when I `make` it. I guess may be unikernel can not support dynamic linking, because includeOS only has one static libray path variable in cmakelist

----------------------Edit--------------------------------

One of the error message:

```
`/home/gavin/libssh/src/wrapper.c:156: undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'`
```

wrapper.c, line 156:

```
  bignum_free(crypto->e);
```

it was defined in `libssh/libcrypto.h` which included by `wrapper.h`

libcrypto.h line 70:

```
#define bignum_free(num) BN_clear_free(num)
```

And I notice that `void BN_clear_free(BIGNUM *a);` is a function defined in openssl library

Could introducing another library cause the problem? 
if so, how could I fix it? 
why dynamic linking dose not have this issue?

Comment: Try `gcc sshtest.c -Llibs -lssh -static -o sshtest`, Or `gcc sshtest.c libs/libssh.a -o sshtest`.

Comment: @joyallen , both of them result to the same error, do you have any idea why the error generated at the path of my cloned repository? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install `libssl-dev`, `cmake` and maybe some other [dependencies](https://github.com/simonsj/libssh/blob/master/INSTALL) if you don't have them already.
2. Build libssh from source with static flags.

   - e.g. extract `libssh-0.9.3.tar.xz` to `/home/user/libssh-0.9.3`
   - `cd /home/user/libssh-0.9.3`
   - `mkdir build && cd build`
   - `cmake ../ -DWITH_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DWITH_STATIC_LIB=ON`
   - `make`
   - now you can use `/home/user/libssh-0.9.3/build/src/libssh.a`
3. Compile your code with `gcc -I/home/user/libssh-0.9.3/include sshtest.c /home/user/libssh-0.9.3/build/src/libssh.a -lssh -lrt -lcrypto -lz -lpthread -ldl -o sshtest -static`
4. You'll still get some *warnings* about shared libraries from the glibc, but resulted binary is completely static.

Presumably you'll need to change include order in your source to 1) stdlib.h, stdio.h etc, 2) libssh/libssh.h. 
And remove `#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1`